# jQuery callback from another function

Tags: jquery, function, post, callback

I have a function that looks like this. It works.

**Problem**

This function `myFunction` is called by many other functions and depending on which one it should do something different on success.

**Question**

How is this solved? Some kind of callback? or do I have to send an extra parameter for the function to know?

**Code**

```
function myfunction()
{
    var value = "myvalue";
    var post_url = "ajax.php";

    $.post(  
        post_url,
        {
             value: value,
        },
            function(responseText){  
                var json = JSON.parse(responseText);
                if(json.success)
                {
                    console.log('success'); 
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function parameter and call it on success:

```
function myfunction(callback)
{
    var value = "myvalue";
    var post_url = "ajax.php";

    $.post(  
        post_url,
        {
             value: value,
        },
            function(responseText){  
                var json = JSON.parse(responseText);
                if(json.success)
                {
                    console.log('success'); 
                    //call callback 
                    callback();

                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have `myfunction` accept a callback:

```
function myfunction(callback)
{
    var value = "myvalue";
    var post_url = "ajax.php";

    $.post(post_url, { value: value }, callback);
}
```

And then you can pass in any function to be executed when the `POST` comes back:

```
myfunction(function(responseText){  
    var json = JSON.parse(responseText);
    if (json.success)
    {
        console.log('success'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will either need to have a parameter to identify the caller, like

```
function myfunction(caller) {
    if (caller == "Foo") {
        // some code
    }
}

myFunction("Foo");
```

Or use a global variable

```
function myFunction() {
    if (caller == "Foo") {
        // some code
    }
}

caller = "Foo";
myFunction();
```